# How to get the data from multiple index in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have a three index, all three index have a diff structure of document(nested), I tried to join the index's,But in ES there is no joins.So, how can i get the data from multiple index's through java high level api??

Any help will be appreciate, thanks in adavnce

```java
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index_1","index_2","index_3");
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user", "kimchy"));
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query multiple Elasticsearch indices in one search operation. The indices can be specified with wildcard patterns, or by listing multiple indices using commas as separators.

But with Client API(Java high level api), You've to convert the index names inside `SearchRequest` into an array of Strings. Java `varargs` expects an Array. **Not sure but something like below.**

```
String[] indexArray = new String[]{"index_1","index_2","imdex_3"}
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexArray);
```

If it doesn't help the  try with Multisearch API, **See**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-multi-search.html#java-rest-high-multi-search

Comment: Why I need to pass the index as a array any how if am passing as a string in search request it will return same result..???

Comment: You should try that and see what it returns mate